# How to Prevent Google's Backup and Sync's Prompt

Tags: macos, google-drive

Every time I connect a device to my computer, an annoying prompt appears asking if I want to upload my media to Backup and Sync (what was formerly Google Drive). I am contemplating uninstalling the software from all of my devices but would first like to explore a way I can change the settings on my computer to prevent the annoying pop up from appearing.

I am technical so I don't shy away from terminal commands if need be. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Running macOS 10.11.6

Answer (score 3):

Under "Preferences" click "USB Devices & SD Cards", then uncheck "Plug in a camera or phone to back up"

Comment: This seems to be valid for all OSes (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't give your OS. If by chance it is linux, it would be worth a shot to look if the mechanism is a udev rule put by google. rules usually reside in a directory called rules.d , in a place like /etc/udev for instance. 'man udev' should shed light on that. You could then have a look at the rules in a text editor. If you find the rule google set, you should rename it as root, i.e. 'sudo mv oldname newname' or such.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing that out. Edited the question to include this info.